How to install 2 versions of libssl on Kubuntu 22.04?
I have SSL 1.1 version in my OS.
I need to install libssl-1.0dev somewhere in home directory for old versions of Python with pyenv. I don't want to change actual verson of libSSL due to security requirements.
I need to do something like this - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/945#issuecomment-409627448
and this - https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#2-your-openssl-version-is-incompatible-with-the-python-version-youre-trying-to-install
But pyenv cannot find old ssl, when I point it.
How can I fix this?
